# Strip special character in ASP

Tags: html, ms-access, encoding, asp-classic

may anyone tell me that how to strip special character in ASP (classic). I'm using MS Access database. I meant is there any function like stripslashes() or addslashes() {PHP}.
Any help will be appriciated

Comment: You have to write it yourself using JavaScript or vbScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function StripSlashes in PHP can be written as

```
function StripSlahes(input)
  StripSlashes = replace(input,"\","")  
end function
```

in ASP.   AddSlashes() is slightly more complex, you need 3 calls to replace

```
function AddSlahes(input)
    AddSlashes = replace(input,"\","\\")
    AddSlashes = replace(AddSlashes,"'","\'")
    AddSlashes = replace(AddSlashes,chr(34),"\"+chr(34))
end function
```