# Replacing " with \" in ASP

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

As the title suggests, I am trying to replacing a " with the escape character \". The reason I am doing this is because there is a quote in my string that represents inches and this string needs to be run through javascript code.

However, when I run my string in the javascript code, it only reads up to the inches character and forgets the rest of the string.

Any and all help is greaty appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, that method is used in PHP and I am working with ASP. Do you know of an ASP equivalent to `addslashes()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function like this will escape `\`, `"` and `'`:

```vbs
function AddSlashes(str)
    AddSlashes = replace(str,"\","\\")
    AddSlashes = replace(AddSlashes,"'","\'")
    AddSlashes = replace(AddSlashes,chr(34),"\" & chr(34))
end function
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7218067/692456)

Comment: Well, it worked. But javascript is still not picking up the escape character for some reason. For example, if `str = "9\""`, javascript only reads 9\. Any solutions?

Comment: You can also use two double quotes to avoid using `Chr`: `AddSlashes = replace(AddSlashes, """", "\""")`

Answer (score 0):

If you define like this `var s = 'some string';`, the quote is work ok, but if you do like `var s = "some string";`, you should replace the quote to `\"`, so the code is `var s = "some string \ " with the quote";`
also you need to replace the Vbcrlf and vbcr and vblf before the JS code